# I am getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException in my project

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-annotations, hibernate-annotations

I am getting UnsatisfiedDependencyException in project
and i have used all jars related with spring-mvc spring-tx hibernate mysql connector and all by using maven tool

type Exception report

```
    message Servlet.init() for servlet kichha threw exception

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet kichha threw exception
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    root cause

    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'feedbackDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/kichha-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
```

**In sts spring tool detail log message**

```
Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule beginWARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:hebbuli' did not find a matching property.
Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.81
Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Aug 11 2017 10:21:27 UTC
Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.81.0
Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:Windows 8.1Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          x86
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_20-b26
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\admin\Documents\LiveProjectWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\tomcat7
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\admin\Documents\LiveProjectWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\tomcat7
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\admin\Documents\LiveProjectWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\tomcat7\endorsed
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_20/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_20/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_20/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;C:\endlessjourny\sts\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.1.RELEASE;;.
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 2040 ms
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.81
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Nov 15, 2017 4:59:56 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/kichha-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
      ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:362)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:399)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
      ... 47 more

    Nov 15, 2017 5:00:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'feedbackDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/kichha-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
      at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
      at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:853)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/kichha-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
      ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:362)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:399)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
      ... 47 more

    Nov 15, 2017 5:00:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet kichha
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.getMetadataSources(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:362)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:399)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
          at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
          at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
          at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
          at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
          at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
          at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
          at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:853)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
          at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
          at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
          at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
          at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
          at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)

**spring configuration file(kichha-servlet.xml)**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.kichha.hebbuli"></context:component-scan>  


    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/telusko"/>
            <property name="user" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="root" />

            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
            <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
            <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.kichha.hebbuli.entity" /> 
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"></tx:annotation-driven>

    </beans>




    **FeedbackDao Class**







    package com.kichha.hebbuli.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.kichha.hebbuli.entity.Feedback;




@Component
public class FeedbackDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Transactional
    public void addFeedback(Feedback fb) {


        System.out.println("In feedback dao"+fb);

        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.save(fb);
    }
}
```

**MAVEN(POM.XML)**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.telusko</groupId>
<artifactId>tusk</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>hebbuli Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.2.9.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
<artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
<version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
<version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>hebbuli</finalName>
</build>
</project>

   Hello guies i have added pom.xml as wel that is maven tool so kindly have a look once again thanking you in advance
```

Comment: Are you added hibernate-core-5.2.10.final.jar in your pom file? Can you please share your pom file details.

Comment: yes added 5.2.9.Final.jar and also shared maven file kindly have a look once please

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem while including hibernate jar files. As per the error line,

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.applyClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lorg/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder;
```

`applyClassLoader` method is present in the [hibernate 5.1](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.html), where as it was not present in [hibernate 4.3](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/registry/BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.html) version

Comment: kindly have a look once pom.xml also added thanks for response